# Pass encoding option in Pyspark text method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, encoding

I have fixed length file encoded in ISO-8859-1.Spark 2.4 is not honoring encoding passed as option.

Below is the sample code(chars got corrupted).

```
g_df = g_spark.read.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").text(loc)
g_df.repartition(1).write.csv(path=loc, header="true", mode="overwrite", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Howeve, when I read it as csv file ,chars are stored as expected.

```
g_df = g_spark.read.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").csv(loc)
g_df.repartition(1).write.csv(path=loc, header="true", mode="overwrite", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This looks like spark does not support encoding for text method.
As this is fixed length file, so I cannot use csv method.

Could you please suggest a way out

Comment: can you read as csv with a non-existent separator? e.g. sep='\u0000'

Comment: Source system is not ready to accept any char as sep, This file has descriptions(provided by user), which could be anything. They may agree to use more than one char as sep like (' ¦~'). .But spark does not support this

Answer (score 0):

Text method does not honor encoding, so I have tried RDD APIS, which is working for me.

Below is the sample code

```
encoded_rdd = sc.textFile(loc, use_unicode=False).map(lambda x: x.decode("iso-8859-1"))
encoded_df = encoded_rdd.map(Row("val")).toDF()
```

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem where i am reading information from a table and encoding the numeric fields with cp037 (ebcdic format for mf). while i am trying to write the result into a text file its giving me a junk characters. Is it possible for you to help me in some way