# Writing Mainframe format file through Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, text, encoding, mainframe

I have a requirement to read a hive db table and write that information in text format in EBCDIC encoding as that will be used as an input to a mainframe process. We are using the cp037 encoding.
To do that i am reading the hive table into a df and then calling a custom udf to convert the numeric value into COMP3 format(used to store numeric value in Mainframe) and then decoding them using cp037 for mainframe EBCDIC charset. Problem is while writing into a text file or displaying the value some extra junk characters are getting added.

First i made sure that the custom udf is working fine. For that i encoded back the output of the custom udf using cp037 and the below output is coming which is perfect and expected. newcol1 here is the MF comp3 equivalent of the field1 and newcol2 is the MF COMP3 equivalent of the field2.

```
root
 |-- field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- newcol1: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- newcol2: binary (nullable = true)
+---------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
|field1         |newcol1               |field2                     |newcol2         |
+---------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
|2023097000     |[00 02 02 30 97 00 0C]|320264                     |[00 03 20 26 4F]|
|2023097000     |[00 02 02 30 97 00 0C]|343012                     |[00 03 43 01 2F]|
|2023100000     |[00 02 02 31 00 00 0C]|343012                     |[00 03 43 01 2F]|
|2023100000     |[00 02 02 31 00 00 0C]|320264                     |[00 03 20 26 4F]|
+---------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
```

But when i am trying to write/display the same after doing decoding junk charcters are coming in

```
after doing decoding
root
 |-- field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- newcol11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- newcol21: string (nullable = true)

+---------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+
|field1        |newcol11|field2                     |newcol21|
+---------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+
|2023097000     |^@^B^B~Pp^@^L |320264                     |^@^C~@^W|   |
|2023097000     |^@^B^B~Pp^@^L |343012                     |^@^C?^A^G   |
|2023100000     |^@^B^B~Q^@^@^L |343012                     |^@^C?^A^G   |
|2023100000     |^@^B^B~Q^@^@^L |320264                     |^@^C~@^W|   |
+---------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+
```

The Mainframe file is like below (Note that i have put HEX ON to show the actual nibbiles)

```
********************************
                                
                                
 -------------------------------
2023097000...Ì.p..320264..Ì..|  
FFFFFFFFFF00073900FFFFFF00722444
20230970000228070C32026403806F00
 -------------------------------
```

If you notice the byte X'78' is the junk character that is getting added.

the pyspark file write command i am using is
df.coalesce(1).write.format('text').option("encoding","cp037").mode('overwrite').save('/some_location/test/comp3_outputdata/')

Seems like while writing into text format it is not supporting the encoding option.

According to the below link it seems like pyspark doesnt support encoding while calling text method.

[Pass encoding option in Pyspark text method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605006/pass-encoding-option-in-pyspark-text-method)

i can't afford to have any other format as my output file will be directly picked up by a mainframe process.
Can somebody please help me with this problem ??

Comment: I am not sure what you try to achieve. COMP-3 is a binary format and has nothing to do with EBCDIC. What do you mean by "decoding them using cp037"? How are you displaying the resulting data? Should the display be able to display EBCDIC?

Comment: @piet.t i am trying to create a file with actual COMP3 value so that the file can be consumed directly by a MF process without doing any type of conversion. Comp3 is a binary format which is part of MF and in MF, EBCDIC is the character set that is used, while cp037 is the actual encoding used in our shop. Without EBCDIC, in my knowledge, COMP3 is not used anywhere in the world. As mentioned in my post the display/logs in the pyspark job is not supposed to properly show the comp3 value (even it is correct). Hence added the MF file screenshot as well to show the erroneous byte..

Comment: Do you have the hex display before the x'78' junk byte is added ?

Comment: In pyspark, is the COMP-3 field represented with an array like `comp-3_binary = b'\x02\x02\x00\x42\x0f'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solving this particular problem statement we have encountered multiple issues and as such writing here a detail process that we followed to resolve the issue for any future reference on this

1. Problem 1 -> Getting junk value in the MF file (which was the original problem statement of this thread).
   For this, as suggested by @Hogstrom we have just encoded the comp specific fields(using cp037) rather than encoding the entire file. Still when we faced the same issue we fixed the sft profile. We have used a MBCS SFT profile with parameters (link given below) to explicitly specify the source and destination encoding. When we did that with source encoding as utf-8 and destination as cp037 the issue got resolved.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cpl?topic=zos-mbcs-conversion-during-microsoft-windows-copy

2. Problem 2 -> In code page cp037, X'15' and X'25' are interchangeable both indicating NewLine. The issue that we faced is that if there is a hex byte of x'15' as part of a comp3 field that value was getting change to x'25'. We did a lot of research and seems like there is no straightforward way to solve it and it's kind of bug in this particular codepage. We discussed with IBM on this and they suggested us to use the code page IBM1047. Note @Hogstrom mentioned this already in his response but somehow i didn't notice that. Note the entire file encoding was still utf8 but the destination encoding is changed from cp037 to cp1047.
3. Problem 3 -> This time we noticed that in each line some extra white spaces are getting added. There is no definite logic for that...for example there was no extra space being added for 2.7 but for 2.5 extra character is getting added. This resulted into a layout issue for us though all the data related issues are resolved. To solved this we forcefully encoded the entire pyspark output file from utf8 to cp1047. Since in pyspark i was writing in text mode and encoding is not supported in that API we have written a separate python code all together for that
4. Problem 4 -> At this point, we noticed that we are getting an extra character x'15' is being added at the end of each rec. This was obvious as the pyspark text write API uses \n as default line-seperator. To resolve this we have used a custom line separator and in the following python code used rstrip to remove that custom line-seperator. this fixed the issue
5. Problem 5 -> Finally in the MBCS sft profile setting, the output file will always be on VB mode while in our case we need to support both VB and FB. As such we have removed the MBCS SFT profile and used simple SFT profile with mode=binary. That satisfied the requirement and created perfect file with perfect layout.

I hope the above steps will help anybody with anytype of issue they might face working on similar requirements.

Answer (score 1):

COMP-3 is a term used in COBOL to refer to packed decimal format on IBM Z hardware.  Other formats include COMP which is binary.  Think of that as an int32.

In the decimal format there are several decimal instructions that can process the number for various arithmetic operations.  It's not clear what you want to do in your question but since you refer to COMP-3 its a reasonable assumption that you want to have a COBOL program process your numeric data as packed decimal and textual information using [CP-037](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/IBM037) codepage.  A side note, CP-037 is generally used in European systems and CP-1047 is used in North American systems.

The binary structure of packed decimal is unrelated to the Code Page.

In your case, you'll need to process each column based on its data type.  In your case you'll have something like this based on your example:

`field1`  - str
`newcol1` - comp-3
`field2`  - str
`newcol2` - comp-3

Rather than converting the entire record using a CP 037 encoding (which is only valid for field1 and field2) you would need to convert field1 and field2 with the conversion.   For newcol1 and newcol2 you want to leave them untouched.  Either copy them to the new output record or leave them untouched.  Since they are binary encoding will result in funky translations like you are seeing with x'78'.

Comment: Hi @Hogstrom as per the business requirement we dont want the cobol part to do any type of conversion on the pyspark output files and they are supposed to process it directly. So if i unpack the 'newcol1' then it will no longer be a comp3 field and the subsequent Cobol code will fail...This is the main reason i want to maintain the comp3 format in the pyspark output itself but unfortunately that is not happening and always 1 byte of junk characters are creeping in. To get a better idea i am adding the Mainframe screenshot as well

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  I think your issue is probably with the sign bit.  Are the numbers always positive or will you have positive / negative numbers

Comment: I added a clarification based on your comments ... unfortunately, you can't simply encode the whole record.  You'll need to manage the columns individually based on their data type.  The COMP-3 must be managed as binary and not undergo encoding.

Comment: appreciate your help. I followed the way you said(and using IBM1047) and it worked. But as of now we are still facing some issue because upon creating the Pyspark file, we noticed that at teh end of every rec we are having some extra bytes of space being added. The number of bytes which are getting added are also not consistent....for some recs 2 bytes for others 1 bytes are getting added. Still working to understand why that is happening