# Writing Mainframe output from pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, encoding, mainframe, ebcdic

Requirement is to create a fixed length output file from pyspark that can be directly read in mainframe z/os environment. There are few comp-3, signed binary fields in the file and trying to find the solution and got this link

[Writing Mainframe format file through Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76031941/writing-mainframe-format-file-through-pyspark/76928189#76928189)

Looking for sample code that was used in the above solution. Anyone faced similar issue and got it resolved.

I tried encoding the fields using cp1047 in pyspark code but I get junk values in the output.